# "Enter a valid time" on Django TimeField using django-bootstrap3-datetime

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-models, django-forms

I'm having issues with time validation when submitting a form using django bootstrap datetime picker. When this form is submitted, I get a "Enter a valid time." error

**models.py:**

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
```

**forms.py:**

```
valid_time_formats = ['%P', '%H:%M%A', '%H:%M %A', '%H:%M%a', '%H:%M %a']

date = forms.DateField(
    widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
                                   "pickTime": False,
                                   "showToday": True,
                                   }))

time = forms.TimeField(
    widget=DateTimePicker(options={
                                   "pickTime": True,
                                   "pickDate": False,
                                   "minuteStepping": 1,
                                   "sideBySide": True,
                                   }),
    input_formats = valid_time_formats
    )


class Meta:
    model = Appointment
    fields = (
        'date',
        'time',
        'duration',
        'cost',
    )
```

**And if helpful, the template:**

```
{% extends 'scheduling/base_scheduling.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block title %}New Appointment{% endblock %}

{% block external %}

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js">
        </script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.js">
        </script>

        {{ form.media }}

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


    {# Load CSS and JavaScript #}

    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript %}

    {# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
    {% bootstrap_messages %}

    {# Display a form #}

    <h1>New Appointment for {{client.full_name}}</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'client_appointment_add' client.id %}" method="post" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% buttons %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {% bootstrap_icon "save" %} Submit
            </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had same error. Setting date format in forms is not enough.

I get rid of it after properly configuring my django datetime settings.

For how to do it right see my answer here: [How to format DateTimeField in Django Admin to localtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470183/how-to-format-datetimefield-in-django-admin-to-localtime/22565251#22565251) 
You will find there also link to example project with right config.

I tested this now with `bootstrap3_datetime`, `bootstrap3` and it works, so it should work for you too.